# How to Identify Candidate Tables for the new feature of SQL Server 2016 Stretch Databases?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

SQL Server 2016 has a new feature, stretch database, that allow you to archive your historical data transparently. but i want to know which tables are good candidates for this feature?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935011.aspx)

> **What kind of databases and tables are candidates for Stretch Database?**
>
> Stretch Database targets transactional databases with large amounts of
>   historical data, typically stored in a small number of tables. These
>   tables may contain more than a billion rows.
>
> In SQL Server 2016 Community Technology Preview 2 (CTP2), Stretch
>   Database migrates entire tables. This assumes that you already move
>   historical data into a table that's separate from current data.
>
> Use Stretch Database Advisor, a feature of SQL Server 2016 Upgrade
>   Advisor, to identify databases and tables for Stretch Database. For
>   more info, see Identify databases and tables for Stretch Database
>   by running Stretch Database Advisor.

[Stretch Database Advisor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn935004.aspx)

[Current limitation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt163698.aspx) (may change in future):

> Table properties
>
> ```
>     More than 1,023 columns
>
>     More than 998 indexes
>
>     Tables that contain FILESTREAM data
>
>     FileTables
>
>     Replicated tables
>
>     Tables that are actively using Change Tracking or Change Data Capture
>
>     Memory-optimized tables
>
>     You can't enable Stretch for a table that has a column named [batchID--N] 
>    or an index named [idx--batchID--N] where N is the object ID of the table.
> ```
>
> Data types and column properties
>
> ```
>     timestamp
>
>     sql_variant
>
>     XML
>
>     geometry
>
>     geography
>
>     hierarchyid
>
>     CLR user-defined types (UDTs)
>
>     Columns that are Always Encrypted
> ```
>
> Column types
>
> ```
>     COLUMN_SET
>
>     Computed columns
> ```
>
> Constraints
>
> ```
>     Check constraints
>
>     Foreign key constraints that reference the table
>
>     Default constraints
> ```
>
> Indexes
>
> ```
>     XML indexes
>
>     Full text indexes
>
>     Spatial indexes
>
>     Clustered columnstore indexes
>
>     Indexed views that reference the table
> ```

Comment: will this feature also helpful for temporary tables?

Comment: Usually a temporary table is emptied and reloaded. It has no 'historical data' because data doesn't stay in it for very long.

Comment: Most of the limitations will go away. In a recent presentation in the SSGAS in India, AlwaysOn. Always Encrypted and Indexed views were mentioned as working in the next CTP release. Check out the release notes with each CTP drop for more removals.